# Github pages 404, not loading repository content

Tags: github-pages

I created chineseantiquebuyers/chineseantiquebuyers.github.io repository, cloned it first then pushed dummy index.html but when checking chineseantiquebuyers.github.io I have 404.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried few different things like, putting files in /docs directory, creating branch gh-pages, and dropping files from some jekyll project.

After dropping jekyll files I finally achieved not having 404 but repository content displayed.

I don't know what issue was.